# GeoServer - WFS-GetFeature Request error: Unable to retype FeatureReader<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> (origional does not cover requested type)

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I am running a WFS-GetFeature-Request via a proxy-Script on GeoServer. The response sent to GeoServer seems to be fine, see xml-head in the  first logs.

Part of the xml-head:

```
    <inversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_PTO xlink:href="urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL6000006LSq"/>
<position>
<gml:Polygon gml:id="o11001.id.295280566.position.Geom_0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833" srsDimension="2">
<gml:exterior>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:posList>402660.625 5826432.222 402683.488 5826400.459 402703.851 5826407.183 402689.885 5826448.839 402662.799 5826439.763 402660.625 5826432.222</gml:posList>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:exterior>
</gml:Polygon>
</position>
<gemarkung>
<AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
<land>12</land>
<gemarkungsnummer>1601</gemarkungsnummer>
</AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
</gemarkung>
<flurstuecksnummer>
<AX_Flurstuecksnummer>
<zaehler>222</zaehler>
</AX_Flurstuecksnummer>
</flurstuecksnummer>
<flurstueckskennzeichen>12160100200222______</flurstueckskennzeichen>
<amtlicheFlaeche uom="m2">1253.00</amtlicheFlaech

09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [data.ows] - Executed request to URL: Myscript.php?PROPERTYNAME=inversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_Darstellung%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_LTO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_PTO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_FPO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_KPO_3D%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_LPO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_PPO%2CtraegtBeiZu%2CistAbgeleitetAus%2CinversZu_hatDirektUnten%2ChatDirektUnten%2Cposition%2CinversZu_verweistAuf%2Cflurstueckskennzeichen%2Cflurnummer%2Cflurstuecksfolge%2CabweichenderRechtszustand%2CzweifelhafterFlurstuecksnachweis%2Crechtsbehelfsverfahren%2Cobjektkoordinaten%2CzeitpunktDerEntstehung%2CinversZu_beziehtSichAuf%2CistGebucht%2CzeigtAuf%2CweistAuf%2CgehoertAnteiligZu%2CbeziehtSichAufFlurstueck&FILTER=%3Cfes%3AFilter+xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3Afes%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Ffes%2F2.0%22+xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%2F3.2%22%3E%3Cfes%3AIntersects%3E%3Cfes%3AValueReference%3Eposition%3C%2Ffes%3AValueReference%3E%3Cgml%3APolygon+srsDimension%3D%222%22+srsName%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%2Fsrs%2Fepsg.xml%2325833%22%3E%3Cgml%3Aexterior%3E%3Cgml%3ALinearRing%3E%3Cgml%3AposList%3E402688.183238+5826421.734022+402726.01865+5826421.734022+402726.01865+5826439.924124+402688.183238+5826439.924124+402688.183238+5826421.734022%3C%2Fgml%3AposList%3E%3C%2Fgml%3ALinearRing%3E%3C%2Fgml%3Aexterior%3E%3C%2Fgml%3APolygon%3E%3C%2Ffes%3AIntersects%3E%3C%2Ffes%3AFilter%3E&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=application%2Fgml%2Bxml%3B+version%3D3.2&SRSNAME=urn%3Aogc%3Adef%3Acrs%3AEPSG%3A%3A25833&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=adv%3AAX_Flurstueck&SERVICE=WFS
09 Jan 15:35:05 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0 https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gco/gco.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd
09 Jan 15:35:05 INFO   [xsd.impl] - https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd
09 Jan 15:35:05 WARN   [xsd.impl] - Error parsing: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd
09 Jan 15:35:05 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd ==> jar:file:/D:/geoserver/GeoServer%202.21.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-gml3-27.2.jar!/org/geotools/gml3/v3_2/gml.xsd
09 Jan 15:35:05 INFO   [xsd.impl] - https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gco/gco.xsd
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not resolve schema location: ../gco/basicTypes.xsd to physical location.
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not locate schema for: ../gco/basicTypes.xsd.
09 Jan 15:35:05 INFO   [xsd.impl] - https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not resolve schema location: ../gmd/metadataApplication.xsd to physical location.
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not locate schema for: ../gmd/metadataApplication.xsd.
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - schema specified by parser configuration not found, supplementing...
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AX_Flurstueck. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}lebenszeitintervall. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}lebenszeitintervall. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}lebenszeitintervall. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AA_Lebenszeitintervall. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
```

This is the error message:

```
    09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zeigtAuf. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zeigtAuf. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zeigtAuf. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Parsing unknown attribute: {http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href
09 Jan 15:35:05 DEBUG  [internal.parsers] - First feature parsed.
09 Jan 15:35:05 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
09 Jan 15:35:05 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException:  error:Translator error
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML2OutputFormat.encode(GML2OutputFormat.java:250)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML2OutputFormat.write(GML2OutputFormat.java:261)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:199)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1018)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Translator error
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:123)
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:101)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML2OutputFormat.encode(GML2OutputFormat.java:247)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to retype  FeatureReader<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> (origional does not cover requested type)
    at org.geotools.data.ReTypeFeatureReader.typeAttributes(ReTypeFeatureReader.java:126)
    at org.geotools.data.ReTypeFeatureReader.<init>(ReTypeFeatureReader.java:98)
    at org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(WFSFeatureSource.java:306)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:626)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:47)
    at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:31)
    at org.geotools.data.crs.ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.openIterator(ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.java:93)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.AbstractFeatureCollection.features(AbstractFeatureCollection.java:66)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.AbstractFeatureCollection.features(AbstractFeatureCollection.java:50)
    at org.geoserver.security.decorators.SecuredFeatureCollection.features(SecuredFeatureCollection.java:40)
    at org.geoserver.security.decorators.SecuredSimpleFeatureCollection.features(SecuredSimpleFeatureCollection.java:75)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.features(DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.java:93)
    at org.geotools.gml.producer.FeatureTransformer$FeatureTranslator.encode(FeatureTransformer.java:572)
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$XMLReaderSupport.parse(TransformerBase.java:1044)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$Task.run(TransformerBase.java:285)
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:119)
    ... 110 more
```

Is there a way to surpass this? I am using GeoServer 2.21.2.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can imagine this happening, is that the GeoServer configuration is out of synch with the actual data, in terms of attributes being available.

Try to go in the layer configuration, and do a "reload feature type".

Comment: I will try that as soon as i get to work on the problem again. I will give an update again.